# Redirect to two different pages using same user name and password in php

Tags: php

I want to write small program in php- My problem statement is, at first time login when user logged into system it redirect to welcome.php then logout from system,but after that same user logged with same user name and password then I want to redirect to another page like(home.php). Please help me?

Comment: well....you can have a column in your db which represent login frequency, if x == 0 => welcome.php, if x > 0 => home.php

Comment: Can you show your current code? You could register the login time in the database and check if it is a returning user for example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to store a flag in your database, maybe in the user table :

```
show_welcome = 1
```

The first time user logs in, the welcome page will be displayed and the flag disabled, so the redirection won't occur next time

Pseudo code :

```
if(login success){
    // Get data from database for current username.

    if(show_welcome) {
        // Redirect to home
    } else {
       // Redirect to welcome,and update in database for show_welcome as 0
    }
} else {
    // Redirect to login with error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean column in your user table `first_login`.

As soon as the user account is created fill the column with `true`. When the user logs in check for `first_login === true` if so goto welcome.php and update the user table and set `first_login` to `false`.

Then the second time he logins in if `first_login === false` just redirect to home.php

Comment: smart logic.. I'll do it.